# Missing gps data

Tags: qgis, gps

When I collect waypoints on my Garmin GPS unit, I can see the lat/long coordinates displayed on the unit. However, when I import the data to QGIS using GPS Tools/Load GPX file, no lat/long coordinates are shown in the resulting attribute table; nor is there any other information other than elevation. How come?

---

*edit:*

Sorry, I now see how to use Field Calculator to insert those values.

However, I'm not seeing how to get the date values shown in my table. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Are the data displayed right in QGIS? If its problem only in the coordinates that missing in attribute table, I think its normal behaviour.

Comment: Which Garmin model are you using and how are you getting the data out of your GPS?

Comment: It's a "GPSmap 62". I use the QGIS "GPS Tools" to import the data.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal behaviour, you have to use **Field Calculator** to add this. Export your waypoints as vector layer (right click `Save as...`), than you can edit its attributes. In attribute table toggle editing mode and in Field Calculator create new fields wtith expressions:

For x coordinates expression `$x`

For y coordinates expression `$y`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "How come?":

In GIS you deal with features. Features are made of a geometry and potentially attributes. The geometry is what "has" the coordinates, they are not considered attributes in GIS models. The user is not meant to care about numeric values of the geometry but use the GIS tools to handle all the spatial stuff.